# Ramifiqué desde una rama en lugar de hacerlo desde la maestra, ¿cómo puedo volver a basar todo menos algunos archivos con la maestra ahora?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Me ramifiqué desde una rama en lugar de hacerlo desde la maestra, ¿cómo puedo volver a basar todo menos algunos archivos con la maestra ahora? Por ejemplo en el siguiente arbol que representa los archivos de mi proyecto, solo quiero guardar las modificaciones de `utils/utms.py`

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume OS
Volume serial number is 68FE-40E4
C:.
│   main.py
│   __init__.py
│
├───mysql
│   │   connect.py
│   │   operations.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           connect.cpython-39.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│
├───task
│       announcement_stats.py
│       anonymization.py
│       users_utm.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───utils
│   │   array.py
│   │   logging.py
│   │   string.py
│   │   utms.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           utms.cpython-39.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│
└───__pycache__
        __init__.cpython-39.pyc
```

Aqui estan mi branches:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl>git branch
  change_subscription_events
  master
* source_attribution
```

Aqui estan mi commits

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools>git log
commit 3e7809f853fa0de6614baa9056d3aeda3296e03b (HEAD -> source_attribution, origin/source_attribution)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 17:19:30 2021 +0200

    changed source and macro source attribution to user

commit 52b796763661809e92ce4d439682c7883996600d (change_subscription_events)
Merge: 670dd7b 48ea030
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
HEAD -> source_attribution, origin/source_attribution)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 17:19:30 2021 +0200

    changed source and macro source attribution to user

commit 52b796763661809e92ce4d439682c7883996600d (change_subscription_events)
Merge: 670dd7b 48ea030
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>


:...skipping...
commit 3e7809f853fa0de6614baa9056d3aeda3296e03b (HEAD -> source_attribution, origin/source_attribution)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 17:19:30 2021 +0200

    changed source and macro source attribution to user

commit 52b796763661809e92ce4d439682c7883996600d (change_subscription_events)
Merge: 670dd7b 48ea030
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 15:29:12 2021 +0200

    Merge branch 'change_subscription_events' of https://github.com/azap/data-tools into change_subscription_events

commit 670dd7bc7c8c4a04702551f27ae6e622b69be7b7
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 14:16:09 2021 +0200
:...skipping...
commit 3e7809f853fa0de6614baa9056d3aeda3296e03b (HEAD -> source_attribution, origin/source_attribution)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 17:19:30 2021 +0200

    changed source and macro source attribution to user

commit 52b796763661809e92ce4d439682c7883996600d (change_subscription_events)
Merge: 670dd7b 48ea030
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 15:29:12 2021 +0200

    Merge branch 'change_subscription_events' of https://github.com/azap/data-tools into change_subscription_events

commit 670dd7bc7c8c4a04702551f27ae6e622b69be7b7
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 14:16:09 2021 +0200

:...skipping...
HEAD -> source_attribution, origin/source_attribution)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 17:19:30 2021 +0200

    changed source and macro source attribution to user

commit 52b796763661809e92ce4d439682c7883996600d (change_subscription_events)
Merge: 670dd7b 48ea030
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 15:29:12 2021 +0200

    Merge branch 'change_subscription_events' of https://github.com/azap/data-tools into change_subscription_events

commit 670dd7bc7c8c4a04702551f27ae6e622b69be7b7
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 14:16:09 2021 +0200

    changed subscription_events to subscriptions
:...skipping...
commit 3e7809f853fa0de6614baa9056d3aeda3296e03b (HEAD -> source_attribution, origin/source_attribution)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 17:19:30 2021 +0200

    changed source and macro source attribution to user

commit 52b796763661809e92ce4d439682c7883996600d (change_subscription_events)
Merge: 670dd7b 48ea030
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 15:29:12 2021 +0200

    Merge branch 'change_subscription_events' of https://github.com/azap/data-tools into change_subscription_events

commit 670dd7bc7c8c4a04702551f27ae6e622b69be7b7
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 14:16:09 2021 +0200

    changed subscription_events to subscriptions

:...skipping...
commit 3e7809f853fa0de6614baa9056d3aeda3296e03b (HEAD -> source_attribution, origin/source_attribution)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 17:19:30 2021 +0200

    changed source and macro source attribution to user

commit 52b796763661809e92ce4d439682c7883996600d (change_subscription_events)
Merge: 670dd7b 48ea030
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 15:29:12 2021 +0200

    Merge branch 'change_subscription_events' of https://github.com/azap/data-tools into change_subscription_events

commit 670dd7bc7c8c4a04702551f27ae6e622b69be7b7
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 14:16:09 2021 +0200

    changed subscription_events to subscriptions

commit 48ea030c07fef0fa9cb9608ec29b26245fe84993 (origin/change_subscription_events)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
:...skipping...
commit 3e7809f853fa0de6614baa9056d3aeda3296e03b (HEAD -> source_attribution, origin/source_attribution)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 17:19:30 2021 +0200

    changed source and macro source attribution to user

commit 52b796763661809e92ce4d439682c7883996600d (change_subscription_events)
Merge: 670dd7b 48ea030
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 15:29:12 2021 +0200

    Merge branch 'change_subscription_events' of https://github.com/azap/data-tools into change_subscription_events

commit 670dd7bc7c8c4a04702551f27ae6e622b69be7b7
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 14:16:09 2021 +0200

    changed subscription_events to subscriptions

commit 48ea030c07fef0fa9cb9608ec29b26245fe84993 (origin/change_subscription_events)
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 26 14:16:09 2021 +0200

    changed subscriptions to subscriptions events

commit 0ebc82738bbf588d173ed30e82fefd99a3d36507
Author: revolucion <revolucionagnie@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 8 16:41:45 2021 +0200

    changed ref to table subscription_events to subscriptions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general lo recomendable sería hacer cherry-pick de las revisiones donde se modifica el archivo (descartando los cambios que esas revisiones introduzcan sobre otros archivos), pero si lo que quieres es dejar un archivo X (su contenido) como está en otra rama *sin tomar en cuenta las revisiones*:

```
git checkout master # digamos que lo queremos en master
git checkout source_attribution -- utils/utms.py # traigo el archivo como esta en la otra rama
git commit -m "me traje el archivo de la otra rama" # coloca un comentario apropiado
```